# Ruby extension link error

Tags: c, ruby, linker, ruby-c-extension

I keep getting this fairly obscure link error whenever I try to link [my Ruby extension](https://github.com/matheusmoreira/mg):

```
/usr/bin/ld: Mg.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `init_window_class_under' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

I couldn't find anything on this. I experimented for a while and it linked fine when I removed the header files, so I moved on without them (Yes, very bad idea).

Turns out I need them, now. So, what is this error exactly, and how do I eliminate it?

**Update:** After clearing everything, I started getting these warnings:

```
warning: ‘init_window_class_under’ used but never defined
warning: ‘init_display_mode_class_under’ used but never defined
```

These also appeared when I first encountered the problem. I'm not exactly sure about what they mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated error is telling you that you're referencing `init_window_class_under` and `init_display_mode_class_under` somewhere but they are not defined. Those functions are actually defined in `Window.c` but they're declared `static` in both the source file and header file. Remove the `static` linkage modifiers from the functions in `Window.c` and declare them as `extern` in `Window.h`. Looks like you're making the same mistake in `Display.c` and everything in the `x11` subdirectory.

Anything declared as `static` has file scope and is not visible outside the file itself.

Your original error:

```
undefined symbol `init_window_class_under'
```

occurs because all the functions in `Window.c` (and `init_window_class_under` in particular) are `static` and `static` functions do not result in any symbols for the linker to find. Only entities with external linkage result in symbols in the object files.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message implies, object files must be built with `-fPIC` to be linked into shared libraries on x86-64 (it's a good idea on other platforms, too).

Add `-fPIC` to your `CFLAGS` and rebuild all objects.

Comment: In the `Makefile` generated by `extconf.rb` there is the line `CFLAGS = -fPIC $(cflags) -fPIC`, and yet it won't compile with it. I also got an old symptom, check my updated question.